# Manually Start LAMP Server

Tags: php, lamp

I setup a LAMP server on my desktop Ubuntu install for testing web applications. How do I set it to only run when I tell it to rather than at startup? It is not used as a production web server but instead for testing PHP scripts I write before pushing them to my public web server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove from start up:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove
sudo update-rc.d mysql remove
```

Start at will:

```
sudo service mysql start
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: in 11.10 I've used sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable :)

Answer (score 13):

This will start Apache, MySql and ProFTPD.

Just write this in terminal:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster C'mon man i just made a silly spelling mistake! :p

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try removing them forcefully.

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
sudo update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

Answer (score 0):

To **start** the server:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

To **restart** the server:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

To **stop** the server:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Comment: Hi there. The user asked for how to change the configuration to disable the application running on startup. You've provided an answer to a different question. You can see the correct answer to this question already posted, using `update-rc.d`.

Comment: @Jeremy That was my first thought, too, but now I'm not so sure. It seems this question has been interpreted to encompass how to manually start the server, considering how [that other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/914527/22949) currently has nine upvotes and zero downvotes. This answer might be regarded as covering the same ground as that... but it also says how to restart and stop the server.